# How do I get code coverage for Xcode for my Objective-C app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

I need code coverage for my iPhone app.

How do I get code coverage for Xcode 4?

Comment: Clang/LLVM don’t have support for gcov and don’t provide code coverage capabilities. You might be able to use gcov with GCC depending on whether your program builds with GCC. See [this bug report at LLVM](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8030) and consider [filing a feature request radar](http://bugreport.apple.com), too.

Comment: You have set UIApplicationExitsOnSusspend to YES in your info.plist

Comment: @Bavarious: According to your bugreport, clang supports coverage now?

Comment: @Joh Yup, nlewycky has added gcov support in LLVM trunk, and nope, the bug report isn’t mine. ;-) I’m not sure if/when Apple will make it available via Xcode, though. You might be able to use it if you build LLVM locally.

Answer (score 9):

These steps will help.

1. Create a new build configuration (‘Coverage’), duplicated from the ‘Debug’ configuration.
2. Open up build settings for the main target, make sure your new configuration is selected, and:

   ```
   Enable “Generate Test Coverage Files”
   Enable “Instrument Program Flow”
   Add “-lgcov” to “Other Linker Flags”
   ```
3. Compile application with Coverage mode.
4. Check .gcno files from your application bundle folder.

   Coverage-iphonesimulator/applicationname.build/Objects-normal

   open .gcno files with CoverStory. Download CoverStory from
   http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/downloads/list

Reference Sites

- http://atastypixel.com/blog/unit-testing-and-coverage-with-xcode/
- http://milesdennis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/code-coverage-in-xcode-4.html

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a good example of this, so hopefully this will help someone else.

If you want to generate HTML from your code coverage (once you get your .gcda files generated), you can install `lcov` and use these commands:

```
function generate-codecoverage-html() {
    if [[ $1 == "-h" || ! $# -eq 2 ]]; then
        echo "    usage: $0 path/to/codecoverage/dir/ path/to/htmldir/"
        return
    fi

    timestamp=$(date)
    tmpfile="/tmp/codecoverage.info-$date"
    lcov --no-checksum --directory "$1" --capture --output-file "$tmpfile"
    genhtml --output-directory  "$2" "$tmpfile"
}
```

Comment: where is 'lcov'?

Comment: found it; https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov  , referenced in https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage