Human readable form of GCC PGO files (.gcda)
I have PGO files (.gcda) generated by my tests (I used GCC 12 with -fprofile-generate=/folder/ in compilation and linking). Is it possible to view .gcda output in human readable form?
I've only managed to dump .gcda files with gcov-dump but I don't know how to interpret output and how to connect it with my source code. Internet isn't helpful here, so I would appreciate hints.

Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/10779539/5382650 help?

This question is similar to: Reading .gcno and/or .gcda files on Mac. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've tried -fdump-rtl-all -fdump-tree-all -fdump-ipa-all options. These are compiler debug settings. Unfortunately, I haven't found much online (parts of some output files looks like Lisp code), so I have to dig it myself. I'll update this question in case of positive results.
