# attempt to call symbol that is not present in system libraries (llvm_gcda_start_file)

Tags: ios5, code-coverage, xcode4.4

I'm trying to follow the instructions in [XCode - Code Coverage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852002/xcode-code-coverage) and [Code Coverage on Xcode 4.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055085/code-coverage-on-xcode-4-4-1)

The .gcno files are generated in DerivedData, but I can't get it to generate the .gcda files.  When I press the home button the logs say:

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone: 
fopen$UNIX2003 called from function llvm_gcda_start_file in image MyApp. 
(lldb)
```

Comment: Answered in [Xcode Code Coverage and fopen$UNIX2003](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575023/xcode-code-coverage-and-fopenunix2003) and [Code coverage with Xcode 4.2 - Missing files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732393/code-coverage-with-xcode-4-2-missing-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Xcode Code Coverage and fopen$UNIX2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575023/xcode-code-coverage-and-fopenunix2003) and [Code coverage with Xcode 4.2 - Missing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732393/code-coverage-with-xcode-4-2-missing-files)

Add the following as a .m file to your project:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fopen$UNIX2003( const char *filename, const char *mode )
{
    return fopen(filename, mode);
}

size_t fwrite$UNIX2003( const void *a, size_t b, size_t c, FILE *d )
{
    return fwrite(a, b, c, d);
}
```